# return a custom data for a field in django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to query an object that has a Char field which I is to be returned with correct datatypes for the corresponding values, upon every orm call for the object.

For instance,

```
class A(models.Model):
    tweet = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=dict)
```

So,

```
>>> a = A.objects.first()
>>> a.tweet
>>> {'x': '1'}
```

This should return, instead:

```
{'x': 1}
```

For some reason, I don't want to save the field the way I expect it to be queried.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure this is a `CharField`, and not a `JsonField`? The result of `a.tweet` should in that case always be a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: This is a string, it's the same as {"x": "1"} _notice double quotes_. You probably meant `JSONField`. However, for your implementation, you'll need to parse this JSON string by `json.loads`.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed The challenge would be then that I'll have to parse it each time this object is called. I thought of writing a custom model manager and alter the queryset a little for this field. But that doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: @twingo this is basically how the `JSONField` that Willem and I mentioned works.

Answer (score 0):

You can [make a custom form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/) and use it to change column data before return.

```py
class CustomCharField(models.CharField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = json.loads(value)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for key, val in value.items():
                    if isinstance(value, str) and value.isdigit():
                        value[key] = int(value)

        return value
```

In `to_python` function you can change value before return from Django orm.